# Upgrading Virtualbox On Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I want to upgrade virtual box on my Ubuntu Server 12.04 box. The original version is 4.1 and the latest is 4.2.

dpkg reports that I need to uninstall the old version to install the new one. Will I lose any data in this process?

Comment: Both virtualbox-ose and virtualbox _are_ 4.1 in the Ubuntu repository

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - it only removes/reinstalls the application itself. All your VMs and other data will remain intact.

Comment: So upon installing and opening the latest version I will see all my old VM's still?

Comment: Yes, and if for some reason you do not see the list (have not seen that happen), you can just re-add it via the Machine->Add menu.